# Any key to produce #{} in a JSF page while working in Eclipse IDE

Tags: jsf, el, facelets, jsf-2.2, eclipse-luna

I am going through the JSF case study based on ***Ed Burns*** book ***The Complete Reference***.
I am tired of typing `#{}` Expression Language syntax.
Is there any combination of keys provided to achieve it in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Don't you get intelligence within those curly braces using some combination of keys like ctrl + space in Eclipse (NetBeans does so with ctrl + space in EL)? The rest is only about those three characters `#`, `{` and `}` which should not be hard to type. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in:

Window > Preferences > General > Keys

Maybe you can make one yourself...